# How to get complete row of one excel sheet using POI API and check the row whether it is present in another sheet?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an issue to get a complete Row using POI. I try to get by traversing column by column. I don't want this methodology. I just want an object of row ( A specific Row) that contains all the respective cell values. And need to check whether this row is present in another given sheet/ excel file.

Is there any single method to get this done.

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you traverse column by column without going through a row?

Comment: `sheet.getRow(rowCount)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single function for that. You'll need to write it. The easiest option is if you are using XSSF and the formatting is going to be the same between the sheets. Then you can just compare `XSSFRow.toString()` of your source string to all the rows in the sheet you are comparing. But that relies on the XML for the whole row to be exactly identical.

If the formatting might be different or you are using HSSF, you're going to need to write a function to build a string or hash for comparison. Either way you are going to need to loop through each row in the sheet to compare to the source row.